# Insert query result into table - SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

This code works great:

```
select month(period) 
from fmdr3.dbo.fmdr_2017
```

It returns the number of the month from a date column.

I'm trying to figure out how to insert the results into the table `FMDR_2017` in a column called `Month`.

I've been trying permutations of this:

```
insert into fmdr3.dbo.fmdr_2017(Month)
    select month(period) 
    from fmdr3.dbo.fmdr_2017
```

but haven't had any success yet.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to update Month column according to period column?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified... the column that I'm pulling the month from is named "period"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll want to update the Month column based on the period?

```
UPDATE fmdr3.dbo.fmdr_2017
SET Month = Month(Period);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to update a value in existing records, is that right?

If so, you need something like this:

```
UPDATE fmdr3.dbo.fmdr_2017
SET [Month] = month(period)
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7c403/1